# Difference between List<int> and Dictionary<int, int>?

Tags: c#

Why would anyone ever use a dictionary with two integers?

It seems to me like this would just create an indexed collection of integers, where the "key" is the integer index and the "value" is the integer.

Or, in other words, it would be the same as a list of integers.

Now, I suppose having a dictionary allows you to set custom integer keys, so for example you could have pairs like (1,2) (7,3), etc. but this still doesn't make much sense. But when would it actually be practical/useful to use a dictionary as opposed to List?

Comment: they serve different purpose.

Comment: "pairs like (1,2) (7,3), etc. but this still doesn't make much sense" I think that makes very much sense. Think of the first number being an identifier for a state, the second number is ment to be the number of inhabitans within that state, only one example.

Comment: A list of ints is just that. A dictionary can map one int to another. Of course, you could abuse the list to use the key as an index, but semantically, they are fundamentally different and should be treated as such.

Comment: Under the hood, a Dictionary is far superior in processing speed. But you would only notice the difference if the collection was large.

Comment: Excellent point. I did not expect to get 5 down-votes within a minute's time, but I see what you mean

Comment: you are totally correct @VerbalKint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if you have a database-table with customers.

And you have another table with orders.

You want to get the number of different orders of every customer from the database.

Then you could save it as a `Dictionary<int, int>`, where the first `int` is the customer's id and the second `int` is the number of different orders they have.

Comment: so every customer can only have one order because key must be unique

Comment: no. Customer's `id` is the `TKey`, and the ID in a normal table is unique. user `1` can have 100 orders, if he'd like. (Orders are, in this example, from another table, as mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

The `TKey` (on a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) is not the index. It is a key value, you do not need to follow a specifique order in the TKey. The `TKey` is just a value you use to get an excatly item on the dictionary. To access an item of the dictionary by index, you can get the index by keys collections. For sample:

```
int key = dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(2); // the 3'rd element

var value = dictionary[key]; // the the value by the key
```

A `List<T>` is a list of value and you can access by the index.

```
var value = list[2]; // get the 3'rd element
```